# service tor start command on Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, tor

If I have a Kali VM connected to a whonix which is another VM on my virtualbox, what exactly happens when I say "service tor start" on my Kali Linux. How is the connection from my kali machine to the internet routed now? Is it affected at all?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @Burgi Many times...However I never understood..how it affects my connection to the internet. No perceivable changes though.

Comment: Your question is attracting close votes as it is too broad, are you able to clarify or narrow to a specific issue you are having?

Comment: @Burgi How is it broad?.. It is very specific as to how my machine's internet connection is affected by the terminal command service tor start?